# Postgres 9.4 jsonb queries basic operators

Tags: json, mongodb, postgresql, jsonb

Is there any way to make queries on a jsonb field in some table in Postgres that are basically equitable to the Mongodb query operators (listed here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/)

I would like to be able to store some json objects in a postgres table for example:

```
{"power": 200},
{"power": 400},
{"power": 0},
{"power": 146297},
```

If I do the current method of

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where json_field ->> 'power' < '2';
```

I get retured both the row for power 0 and power 146297...

Is there some documentation somewhere that specifies how to do

gt, gte, lt, lte, eq, not equal, in array, not in array

Comment: Postgres 1.4? [Seriously?](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: `jsonb` supported from 9.4, it must be a typo (but please update your question to be sure).

Comment: Yeah type - should be 9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `->>` string result values:

```
WITH mytable(json_field) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"power": 200}'::JSONB),
  ('{"power": 400}'::JSONB),
  ('{"power": 0}'::JSONB),
  ('{"power": 146297}'::JSONB)
)
SELECT * FROM mytable where (json_field->>'power')::INTEGER < 2;
```

Result is:

```
  json_field  
--------------
 {"power": 0}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is on the [postgresql page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). The documentation states that the `->>` operator returns string, your right hand operand is a string too so the result is correct.

To do what you wanted to do you must cast the result returned from the json to integer:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where (json_field ->> 'power')::int < '2';
```

Please note the brackets are needed as not to case 'power' to int.